# Set limit camera screen WITDH

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

Look my game has a fixed camera, configured as a standard 1280x720.

I placed at each end of the cam width of an empty object with a collider to prevent the player pass this point.

Everything works perfectly until the default resolution decreases. When I run the test with 480x320 screen width decreases, but the collider, does not follow this decrease, staying out of the screen, which makes the player to be "cut off."

The following two images:

First: 1280x720
Second: 480x320

[image: 1280 x 720]

[image: 480x320]

There is some way which I can **only** set the side margins left and right of the camera as a collider?

If it is not possible to configure only the edge of the camera as a delimiter, the player would have some other way to do something to solve my problem?

Some items fall from the sky, so I can not have a collider at the top of the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. The easiest way is to create a 4 box collider 2D and position them to the edge of the screen.

I always use [this](http://pastebin.com/SLUzKpTg) complete script to do this. It's too long to post here. Just attach it to an empty GameObject in the scene. It will do the rest of the work for you. I will create the colliders and position them to the edge of the scrren automatically.

Comment: Programmer, ty again! Copy, past, attach, voilà,  all problems gone.

Answer (score 0):

As what i have understand my be this can help you

[Scale box collider to camera view](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/509466/scale-box-collider-to-camera-view-1.html)